# Problem with android zebra emdk plugin tutorial

Tags: android, scanning

I was checking the tutorial for the zebra emdk at http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/7-1/tutorial/tutBasicScanningAPI/
and the tutorial is kind of sloppy and does not work from my end, there are a few unused variables, so it seems like something is missing, if someone could provide me with a better source for a simple scanner app or if already did the tutorial before and knows what could be missing, please provide some feedback, thanks in advance.[Example of unused code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1fdt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found this repository in the Zebra examples and it actually works:
https://github.com/Zebra/samples-emdkforandroid-6_9